# Update particular value in the list in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

i am learning mongodb  and using python in tornado.

the data stored in the table:

```
t5 = [ 
{
"Pid" : "1111",
"Rid": "666",
"Amount": 3000
 }
 {
 "Pid" : ["1111","2222"],
 "Rid": "777",
 "Amount": 4000
 }
]
```

i would like to update  the data values in the table:

```
h = [
{"Pid" : "1111",
"Rid": "666"
"Amount": 2000
}
]
```

but i got error,

my desired output is like this I want only the `Amount` to be updated

```
[{
"Pid" : "1111",
"Rid": "666"
"Amount": 2000
}
{    
"Pid" : "1111",
"Rid": "777"
"Amount": 0
}]


since there is no match for the second Rid: 777 I want the amount to be 0
```

The `Amount : 4000` is for the `Pid:2222` that is why it should be set to 0

I have tried to do this by using `itertools` like this

```
per_id = {}
for info in chain(h, t5):
    print("info", info)
    per_id.setdefault(info['Rid'], {}).update(info)
res = list(per_id.values())
```

but its not working, I am getting the output as:

```
[{
"Pid" : "1111",
"Rid": "666"
"Amount": 2000
}
{    
"Pid" : "1111",
"Rid": "777"
"Amount": 4000
}]
```

how can i achieve this in mongodb ,please anyone help me

Comment: what error you got and could you show your code

Comment: you want to have the update query or your code (that perform update query) fixed? If it's the second one post your code

Comment: your expected output runs me to think that you want to merge 2 documents into a single one, but probably you need an array of what for you represents the combination of "Pid","Rid","Amount". Let's assume this is an object called "transaction", making an array could be the solution.

Comment: @StefanoSaitta yes you are right and I am not aware of how to create an object and do so.

Comment: @The6thSense I have edited my question, please have a look